# Unable to register for Apple Push Notification Service on Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I downloaded the [PushyMac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PushyMac/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application from Apple website but cannot figure out why I couldn't register for push notification upon application startup. Here's the error I get

```
2013-02-27 19:53:49.737 PushyMac[61525:303] applicationDidFinishLaunching:
2013-02-27 19:53:49.738 PushyMac[61525:303] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
    notification name NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
2013-02-27 19:53:49.753 PushyMac[61525:303] application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: with
error = Error  Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation
couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1.)" (kCFHostErrorHostNotFound / 
kCFStreamErrorSOCKSSubDomainVersionCode / kCFStreamErrorSOCKS5BadResponseAddr / 
kCFStreamErrorDomainPOSIX / evtNotEnb / siInitSDTblErr / kUSBPending / dsBusError / 
kStatusIsError / kOTSerialSwOverRunErr / cdevResErr / EPERM:  / Error code is the version 
of SOCKS which the server wishes to use /  / POSIX errno; interpret using <sys/errno.h>  / 
event not enabled at PostEvent / slot int dispatch table could not be initialized. /  / 
bus error /  /  / Couldn't get a needed resource; alert / Operation not permitted)
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Looks like maybe some socks proxy problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when your app is not code signed properly

Comment: Not sure what you really mean with "not properly" here. I tend to think my signing is "proper", and I still have that error. I asked as well here to see: https://devforums.apple.com/message/939368#939368

Comment: @StuFFmc what does codesign -v [PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE] output

Comment: What does "properly" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I just received the same error message after signing out and signing back in to iCloud on my Mac. I resolved it by going to the Capabilities tab of my target in Xcode. Under iCloud, a problem was shown, which was automatically fixed by pressing the fix button.